Solar panel used to trickle charge four 12 V batteries
I am attempting to use a solar panel to charge four 12V AGM batteries. These are connected to batteries on quad bikes. We are hoping to allow them to trickle charge while they are in the garage. The solar panel is a 12V and 50W solar panel for trickle charging that is linked here.
I am using 10AWG wire and the same SAE connectors that are on the solar panel. The diagram below shows what the design looks like. The batteries will be connected in parallel to the solar panel charger. Each 12V battery will have its own SAE connector that can be attached to the battery as well as an inline fuse, and there is one connector that attaches to the solar panel.
Before I try connecting everything, I wanted advice on how to handle the possiblity of back current from the batteries. Do I need to include a diode to prevent back current? Also, is there something I should do to ensure that the batteries discontinue charging when they are at full capacity? I imagine there may be a chip that prevents overcharging when I connect to one battery, but I am not sure how that would work when four batteries are attached. Also, is there anything I am not considering that could cause a problem with this design?


what type of batteries are you charging?

Without isolation diodes, fuses would pop almost immediately, if there were even 0.1 V difference between batteries' charge (and the fuse is needed to prevent fire). Also, as @jsotola implies, some batteries can tolerate continuous uncontrolled trickle charge, with slightly shortened service life (e.g., NiMH with catalyst), some with much shortened life (e.g., Pb-acid), and some might catch fire (e.g., Li-ion). A charge controller is suggested.

@jsotola they are AGM batteries

@SamanthaGarcia that information belongs in the question ... please add it there... it does not belong in a comment

One cannot simultaneously charge 4 independent batteries that are at different states of charge (SOC) directly from a single charge controller (in this case the charger is built onto the solar panel).  As DrMoishe Pippik pointed out in the comments and the original poster suspected, when multiple batteries at different states of charge are connected in parallel, they will try to quickly balance to the same voltage across all connected batteries. In other words, the battery with highest SOC/voltage will discharge into the other batteries with maximum very high current -- BAD things will happen (but hopefully the fuses will open fast enough to prevent a fire, or maybe the battery has a BMS that will go into protection state).
As original question suggested, the full-battery-to-empty-battery discharge current could be prevented by adding LARGE diodes to each parallel battery feed circuit such that only charging current can flow (not discharging current), which would prevent the batteries from balancing to eachother.  However, initially only the lowest SOC (lowest voltage) battery will charge at all, until that battery raises to the same SOC as another battery.  Then those two batteries will charge together at one-half the original rate. Eventually all the batteries will reach the same SOC, but the charge controller would not sense the true voltage of the batteries because of the diode forward voltage drop in the circuits. Thus, the charge controller (in the solar panel) will think the batteries are full at incorrect voltage and stop charging too early.  If the charge controller was fully programmable, perhaps this could be compensated out by raising the charging voltage. Also, remember that the diodes will dissipate significant heat and waste power from the solar cell causing even a single connected battery to charge slower than without the diode.  Each diode would need to be sized to accept the maximum charging forward current (5A or higher for 50W charger).
Charging four independent batteries simultaneously would best be accomplished with four independent battery charge controllers.  Perhaps to accomplish the overall goal charging from solar power, each battery charger could draw from a single common energy source, such as a larger higher voltage battery that is maintained by a solar panel. For example, a single 24V solar panel with charge controller could be permanently connected to a large 24V battery (stationary with solar panel), and then connect additional four 24VDC-to-12VDC battery chargers as loads to that system.  Each of those could then charge one of the mobile batteries.
